# Why does the following tuples have different hashes

Tags: python, hash, tuples

I have 2 different methods 
func1 return hash(tuples)
main return hash(t)

but hash is different while tuples identical 
Code below:

```
def func1(n):
    list11 = []
    [list11.append(input('Enter a value: ')) for i in range(0,n)]
    t = tuple(list11)
    print(hash(t))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    n = int(input())
    integer_list = map(int, input().split())
    t = tuple(integer_list)
    print(hash(t))
    func1(2)
```

Comment: Don't use list comprehension for its side effect, you're needlessly creating a `list` object.  If you don't need the resulting `list`, just use a for loop instead.

Comment: @jasonharper I assume OP is very new to Python (as we all once were **:)**); I think it would be more helpful if you gave OP some insight into *why* those hashes are different, even if it seems obvious to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without regard to the quality of the code, the problem is that you forgot to
cast `input()` to `int` in the function, but you did so for the tuple in `__main__`, so they're not the same tuple.

```
[list11.append(int(input('Enter a value: '))) for i in range(0,n)]
```